# how to apply vlookup formula on filtered data/visible cells only

Tags: vba, excel

I have filtered column "A" and i need to apply vlookup formula on the visible cells in column "A". How do i achieve this in vba . number of total rows in the worksheet are 30,000 and the filtered rows are closed to 100.

Comment: Can you sort the sheet?

Comment: No. Order in which the data exists is not meant to be changed

Comment: You will need to loop through the visible cells using `Range("A2:A100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` then when the value is found use offset to find the correct value.

Comment: You can use FILTER in VLOOKUP to achieve this without VBA.
```=VLOOKUP(<search_key>, FILTER(<filter_range>,<filter_criteria>),<result_col_index>, <sort_flag>)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this problem without VBA, just with an Excel array formula.
But if you wish to set this formula with VBA, just use the [Range.FormulaArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104.aspx) property.

We are using this array formula:

```
{=VLOOKUP(A2,IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table2!$B$2:$B$5,ROW(Table2!$B$2:$B$5)-ROW(Table2!$B$2),0,1)),Table2!$B$2:$C$5,0),2,0)}
```

To use it in Excel you need to paste it without the enclosing curly brackets and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> (Mac) to activate the array formula.

---

**How does the formula work?**

The data sheet `Table2` looks like this:

```
  Column A    Column B    Column C
┌  ─  ─  ─  ┬  ─  ─  ─  ┬  ─  ─  ─  ┐
│   Month   │   Store   │  Revenue  │
├  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┤
│    Jan    │     1     │   6.000   │
├  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┤
│    Jan    │     2     │   8.000   │
├  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┤
│    Feb    │     1     │  10.000   │
├  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┤
│    Feb    │     2     │  12.000   │
└  ─  ─  ─  ┴  ─  ─  ─  ┴  ─  ─  ─  ┘
```

The data sheet is filtered by month, so that February is visible only.
The result will be look like this:

```
  Column A    Column B
┌  ─  ─  ─  ┬  ─  ─  ─  ┐
│   Store   │  Revenue  │
├  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┤
│     1     │   10.000  │ Formula: {=VLOOKUP(A2,IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table2!$B$2:$B$5,ROW(Table2!$B$2:$B$5)-ROW(Table2!$B$2),0,1)),Table2!$B$2:$C$5,0),2,0)}
├  ─  ─  ─  ┼  ─  ─  ─  ┤
│     2     │   12.000  │ Formula: {=VLOOKUP(A3,IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table2!$B$2:$B$5,ROW(Table2!$B$2:$B$5)-ROW(Table2!$B$2),0,1)),Table2!$B$2:$C$5,0),2,0)}
└  ─  ─  ─  ┴  ─  ─  ─  ┘
```

*My answer is based on this [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SmU2kdt1ig).*